# Node-Red Position SVG elements over an image

Tags: html, css, svg, node-red

I would like to display an image in my node red dashboard and color a certain area on a special condition.
To do so, I created svg rectangles and would like to position them over the image as described in this stack overflow post: [Position SVG elements over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806515/position-svg-elements-over-an-image)

Unfortunately the rectangles are always displayed below the image. Does anyone know how to lay the svg recangles over the image? Or is there an easier solution to color the area?

```css
.bild{
    position: absolut;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.form{
    position: absolut;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<img class="bild" src="image.png"/>


<svg class="form">
    <rect class="g1"  width="150" height="150" fill={{msg.gb1}} opacity="0.1" />
    <rect class="g2"  width="150" height="100" fill={{msg.gb2}} opacity="0.1"/>
    <rect class="g3"  width="150" height="100" fill={{msg.gb3}} opacity="0.1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: When you say the rect is "below the image", do you mean lower on the screen -- or "behind" the image? I suspect using the English spelling `position: absolute` will make it behave differently.

Comment: I ment blow in terms of lower on the screen. And the right spelling helpt with the solution - thank you!